# Tensorflow concatenate tf.data.Dataset.list_files

Tags: python, file, validation, tensorflow

I'm running my current code on a data set which has the following naming convetions:

Training files: training-??-?? where the ?? are wildcards (placeholders for any range).
The same convetion goes for validation and test files (e.g. validation-??-??).

In my code I create the file pattern like this:

```
training_file_pattern = os.path.join(config['data_dir'], "training-??-of-??")
```

But now I wanted to train my model also on the validation and training set together. But I'm having problems figuring out how I can take both datasets. For training I would do:

```
tf_data_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(training_file_pattern, seed=1234, shuffle=self.shuffle)
```

I thought to do the same with the validation set and concatenate it to like this:

```
tf_data_files = tf.concat(tf_data_files, tf.data.Dataset.list_files(validation_file_pattern, seed=1234, shuffle=self.shuffle))
```

But it doesn't work correctly. What would the correct way to do it?
I also tried to define the file_pattern differently to contain also validation but I don't know how to do it without taking also the test set (they are all in the same folder). So I cannot do this:

```
training_and_validation_file_pattern = os.path.join(config['data_dir'], "?-??-of-??")
```

Because this would also take the test set right?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your point, you can simply do

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.listdir('path'))
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(dataset)
```

Dataset API also has concatenate method

```
dataset = dataset_1.concatenate(dataset_2)
```

but it's not completely clear wether you need it
Edit:
`list_files` will create dataset with filenames
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(['f1.csv', 'f2.csv'])

```
for i in ds:
    print(i) #output 'f1.csv'
```

I'm using TF 2.0 version just for clarity.
On the other hand, `tf.data.TextLineDataset()` outputs actual values form text file, like

```
tf.Tensor(b'0.7079635943784122,0.9659163071487907'
```

So using just `list_files` will create dataset from files, not their contents and will require to apply additional parse function to dataset

Comment: No, I don't want to concatenate, I would like to take all the data from a directory with different naming structure. What does you first line do?

By searching around I realised that I might be able to just do this `tf_data_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files([training_file_pattern, validation_file_pattern], seed=1234, shuffle=self.shuffle)`. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it but it doesn't throw any error. But I'm not sure if it is really taking both paths. I would appreciate if someone could clarify if this works. Thanks

Comment: OK thanks this make things more clear, but is it correct what I wrote in my last comment? That I can utilize more paths in an "array" (see the brackets) and hence create a dataset with all the files from those paths?

Comment: Sure, using os module you can pass more complex pathway to tf dataset